# How to rename routine name and save routine code in mysql workbench 6.0.9 community version in Mac OSX

Tags: mysql-workbench

Mysql Workbench 6.0.9 community version doesn't have the routine rename menu and can't save the routine code change in Mac OS X through the routine editor.

[image: No Routine Rename]
[image: Can't save the routine code]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for a workaround. Just edit the name in the code which will then be parsed out and appear as tab title and in the overview area.

Comment: Can't change the code in 6.0.9. In the previous version, I use the way you mentioned. But in the latest version. It can't work. Even I manually save the model file after change the routine code, the change won't be kept. That is why I come out this post.

Comment: I just tried with 6.0.9 on Mac and it works for me. It's usually changed when you leave the editor.

Answer (score 0):

The only workable way is "routine group"

1. create a routine group by clicking the "Add Group" icon
2. open the group by click the created group icon as above
3. add the created routine into the group through the drag & drop
4. switch the group routines editor by clicking the bottom tab "Routines"
5. when edit the body of the routines, the change will be effective immediately and the change will be saved after you save the model

The following is the screen for the above steps

[image: Routine in Group] [image: Change Routine]